# Efficiently drop dataframe rows where *index* contains nulls (NaT)

Tags: python, pandas, null

My data files infrequently contain malformed lines (think abrupt power loss). When badness occurs across a timestamp, making it uninterpretable, the resulting `DataFrame.Index` contains Not-a-Time (`NaT`) values (because I've coerced it to).

My real problem is that instances of `NaT` prevent the use of `resample`. I need to remove them, first. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out if/how to use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on the index itself. It's looking more and more like I need to make the index a column, operate on it, then re-make it the index. (But I don't want to do that.)

Is there an established idiom for dropping dataframe rows where the `Index` values are null?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use

```
df.loc[pd.notnull(df.index)]
```

for newer versions you can do

```
df.loc[df.index.notnull()]
```

or

```
df.loc[df.index.dropna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @EdChum s answer

```py
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

will do what you are looking for in one line. No need to redefine the variable. It can be a bit easier on memory usage as its a built in pandas function. (Sorry I didn't comment this. My rep is still too low, but I thought this solution should still be on this question).

Comment: This will do more than the question asks, use carefully. will also drop missing values from the dataframe, not only the index as asked.